# AssertJ + Verify items in subset of list from the extracted list

Tags: extract, assertj

So, have an use case where in I extract title from the object, as list say 10 items, now need to verify the title is present in anyof the first 5 items.
Using below method to extract the items.But not sure how to reduce the list and verify it.

```
softAssertions.assertThat(resultArrayList)
                      .extracting("title")
                      .as("Title match")
                      .isEqualTo(placeToSearch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this with AssertJ, I think the easiest solution would be to take the 5 first elements and simply use `contains` as in:

```
softAssertions.assertThat(resultArrayList.subList(0, 5))
                  .extracting("title")
                  .as("Title match")
                  .contains(expectedTitle);
```

Note that using `isEqualTo` does not work in your example unless it corresponds to the exact list of the expected titles.

Comment: Thanks Joel Costigliola, it worked as expected. Also in the above way, do we have a way to get the matched index.

Comment: Nope, you won't  get the matched index in my suggestion